# How to resolve Rust's "use of moved value" in method design?

Tags: rust

I have a System, which will connect multiply API downstreams. I would like to use

```
let mut system = System::new()
```

to intake config and do the validation, then use
`system.init()`
to init all connections for the downstreams.
After it connects all downstreams, I would like to make multiple methods to do CRUD to the downstreams.

Here's the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3c60053ee3dce5c60799d281fb8d887b)

```
struct Conn {
    connection: String,
}
impl Conn {
    fn fetch(&mut self) -> &str {
        self.connection.push_str("data");
        &self.connection
    }
}

struct System {
    downstream: Option<Conn>,
}

impl System {
    fn new() -> Self {
        System { downstream: None }
    }

    fn init(&mut self) {
        self.downstream = Some(Conn {
            connection: String::from("db connection"),
        })
    }

    fn method_a(self) -> String {
        let mut conn = self.downstream.unwrap();
        String::from(conn.fetch())
    }
    fn method_b(self) -> String {
        let mut conn = self.downstream.unwrap();
        String::from(conn.fetch())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut system = System::new();
    system.init();

    println!("{}", system.method_a());
    println!("{}", system.method_b());
}
```

However, because `system.method_a()` moved the ownership at `unwrap()`, so when I call the second method `system.method_b()` after the first one. Obviously, I will get the error "use of moved value".

I understand how and why the error happens. But I don't know what's the idiomatic way to deal with this situation.

One workaround way is use `Conn` instead of `Option<Conn>`, but if don't use Option, then I have to init all downstream connections in `System.new()` and all downstreams can't have the value of "None".

So my question is how I design a module to fix my purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question: why do method_a and method_b take System by value rather than by reference? Because that seems the simplest fix.

Comment: @user1937198 correct me if I'm wrong, but then you can't call `unwrap` on the `downstream` `Option<Conn>`, as `unwrap` takes ownership of the contained value ([source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap))

Comment: Because in method_a/method_b, I need to take the Conn out from the Option by using `unwrap()`. It inherently moved the ownership of the System.

Comment: `Option::as_ref` / `Option::as_mut` will convert an `&[mut] Option<T>` to an `Option<&[mut] T>`, letting you `unwrap` it and get a reference to the wrapped structure.

Comment: In the System struct, it looks to me as if having downstream being 'non-None' is an invariant as soon as the `init` method is called. One could argue that there should be two different types. One implementing the init method, and a second one returned from init containing a Conn instead of Option<Conn>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the example you provided, you could change `method_a` and `method_b` to take a mutable reference instead. `conn` itself just calls `fetch()` which uses mutable ref.

```rust
fn method_a(&mut self) -> String {
    self.downstream
        .as_mut()
        .map(|conn| String::from(conn.fetch()))
        .unwrap()
}

fn method_b(&mut self) -> String {
    self.downstream
        .as_mut()
        .map(|conn| String::from(conn.fetch()))
        .unwrap()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1697a9a4f886432bb2b44ef349841247)

For undertanding purposes, you could also write the above method as:

```rust
fn method_a(&mut self) -> String {
    match self.downstream {
        Some(ref mut conn) => String::from(conn.fetch()),
        None => panic!(),
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f8927631bf2973fd5eb2baf00cdb5972)

And if the above code is just an example snippet and you need ownership of `conn` for some reason, you can do it by [`take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) and if that also doesn't work then you will have to make your struct implement [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) trait so you can clone it instead of moving.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Especially, the second example, excellent explained my question.
Thank you @Mihir.